# Ошибка в boost/ublas/storage.hpp при интегрировании жесткой системы

Tags: c++, boost

При компиляции кода, который интегрирует жесткую систему диффуров, получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Check failed in file D:/MinGW/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp in line 195 (Element access):

i < size_
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_index'

what(): bad_index
```

Ошибка появляется сразу при входе в `integrate_const(stepper, ode, x, t_0, t_max, dt)`, где `stepper = make_dense_output< rosenbrock4< double > >(abs_err, rel_err)`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Так как я нуб в проге, буду благодарен за любые советы!

Comment: Сообщение достаточно ясное: индекс элемента (i) превышает общее количество элементов (size).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я действительно забыл определить размер интегрируемого вектора :(